# gnome-disks shows two external disks as one

Tags: gnome-disk-utility

Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, plugging i n two external disk drives (both 2.5" SATA disks in enclosures). Gnome disks somehow detects only one, and shows one entry, in the title it combines both `/dev/sdd` and `/dev/sdc` together.
[image: disks UI]

fdisk and gparted detect the disks as two separate disks. Any idea how to get gnome disks to identify the disks as two?

```
fdisk -l 
Disk /dev/sdd: 465.78 GiB, 500107861504 bytes, 976773167 sectors
Disk model: Expansion       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 70F39BAE-21F1-4AB3-956A-B87F9CC19803

Device        Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1      2048   4196351  4194304    2G Linux swap
/dev/sdd2   4196352   8390655  4194304    2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd3   8390656  75556863 67166208   32G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdd4  75556864 100132863 24576000 11.7G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: 00SSD1          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 07625555-5CA7-4D51-9CEE-0C101DC5B494

Device        Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1        34   4194239   4194206    2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc2   4194240  71302079  67107840   32G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdc3  71302080 910150079 838848000  400G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Since identical sectors, are they RAID or some sort of Microsoft dynamic partitioning? Do any Linux tools show it as LDM? Shown as SFS in fdisk, Dynamic also on gpt as LDM

Comment: @guiverc I am using `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` the fdisk was from a ssh window )headless), not sure if that mattered.

Comment: @oldfred I created the identical size partitions to pair them in raid1.

Comment: "I created the identical size partitions to pair them in raid1"......  what else did you do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add important information like "I created the identical size partitions to pair them in raid1" I'm the question. We are not playing "Guess what have I done?"